# How to use the type "c"and "C" in kdb

Tags: kdb

When i used `meta tableName` to check type .get below result :

```
c                t        f      a
`description     "C"
```

And now I want to know the diff between type `"c"` and `"C"`. and how to cast the type `"c"` into `"C"`.

From the following explanation I can get that when there is a "c" type in a table, I can convert it to "C" type. My new question is as follows:
    table1:

```
([ID:`1`2`3]Name:`A`B`C;Client:`P`Q`S;Species:`setosa`setosa`setosa   ;Length:2 34 6)
```

showing as below:

```
ID Name  Client    Species  Length
 1    A     B        setosa    2
 2    B     Q        setosa    34
 3    C     S        setosa    6
```

And I want to write a simple api for table1:

```
.get.table1:{[Params]
  if[Params~();Params:()!()];
   select ID:ID,NAME:Name,CLIENT:Client,SPECIES:Species,LENGTH:Length,DESCRIP:count[i]#enlist "" from table1
    }
```

result:`.get.table1[]`

```
ID NAME  CLIENT    SPECIES  LENGTH  DESCRIP
 1    A     B        setosa    2       ""
 2    B     Q        setosa    34      ""
 3    C     S        setosa    6       ""
```

meta table1:

```
c             t   f   a
ID            s
NAME          s
CLIENT        s
LENGTH        j
DESCRIP       C
```

Now, I want to change the writing style of an api to get the same result as the api above. What should I do?(How to describe the DESCRIP line)

```
.get.table1:{[Params]
   if[Params~();Params:()!()];
   defaultCols:`ID`NAME`CLIENT`SPECIES`LENGTH`DESCRIP!(`ID;`Name;`Client;`Species`;`Length;**DESCRIP**)
   if[`extraCols in key Params;
   extraCols:$[-11h=type Params`extraCols;enlist[Params`extraCols]!enlist 
Params`extraCols;(Params`extraCols)!Params`extraCols];
defaultCols:defaultCols,extraCols];
?[select from table1;();0b;defaultCols]

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type "c" means that each element is in the column is atomic, whereas type "C" means that each element in the column is a list of that type. To convert from "c" to "C" you can enlist each character to make it into a list.

```
q) meta ([] c:"123")
c| t f a
-| -----
c| c

q) meta ([] c:enlist each "123")
c| t f a
-| -----
c| C
```

Querying a string column will be inefficient. If your column has a small set of distinct values that are repeated often, casting the column to a symbol column will be more efficient

Answer (score 2):

Type "c" is a single character (atom). Type "C" is a list of characters. Here are some examples that might help demonstrate things:

```
q)tbl:([] col:"abc")
q)meta tbl
c  | t f a
---| -----
col| c    
q)tbl
col
---
a  
b  
c  
q)update col:enlist each col from `tbl / "cast"
`tbl
q)meta tbl
c  | t f a
---| -----
col| C    
q)tbl
col 
----
,"a"
,"b"
,"c"
```

So the "cast" is simply an enlist. Be careful if the column is mixed with atoms and lists, as a "enlist each" will not give you what you want. You'll have to conditionally enlist just those values that are just atoms, using something like this.

```
q)enl:{$[0h>type x;enlist x;x]}
q)update col:enl each col from `tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way of doing it :

```
q)t:([] x:"abc")
q)meta update ("",/:x) from t
c| t f a
-| -----
x| C
```

The good part of appending an empty string is that, if the elements are already a list it won't have any impact

```
q)t:([] x:"",/:"abc")     / each element is already a list 
meta[t]~meta update ("",/:x) from t
```

However, applying `enlist` will change the data type to heterogeneous list (`type 0h`):

```
q)t:([] x:"",/:"abc")
q)meta update enlist each x from t
c| t f a
-| -----
x|
```